# On First load FireFox makes mess of css

Tags: css, firefox

I faced really strange problem. FiroFox in production are messing with css, in Edge, Chrome and Safari everything works just fine except in Firefox. On first load after clearing cashe all css seems deactivated and html elements stands in random places. Examples below to show the results

How it looks on firs load in FireFox :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIXBO.png)

How it should look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk0qC.png)

React JSX, that's how the html structure looks like. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq8TX.png)

Just remember in other browsers it works like a charm.

PS. It only happens in live production, working on localhost in Firefox it works just fine.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No console is clear.

Comment: Please show us the code. It sounds as though something is not waiting for something to load but this is just a guess.

Comment: Just updated post added JSX picture of images.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.